# How to get started in The Castle Doctrine?

Tags: the-castle-doctrine

I'm a bit at a loss. Sure, the basic concept is booby-trapping one's own house sufficiently such that no one can harm your family or steal from your vault, while trying to save some money so one can afford the tools to bypass other homes' defences. But what is a simple setup for starters?

Answer (score 1):

Your $2000 starting cash is enough to buy a small combination of home defense structures. I like to buy a pair of pit bulls and put them in hallways such that a successful route to the vault has one or both chasing you the entire way. I put in a bunch of doors with dead ends behind them, and some battery-switch-grate combos that form a commitment trap in front of one or two sets of dead ends, and finally I buy a shotgun for the wife.

If your traps are clever enough, you'll quickly start earning some cash from dead invaders, but this starting layout is not remotely sufficient for anyone who sank their entire 2k into tools, so the sooner you can earn enough to buy a pit trap or two, the better.

I strongly recommend finding videos like this one from YouTube user Aavak to give you a better idea for home defense basics: